# How to find sources in a 2d vectorfield?

Tags: vector-fields

Imagine a 2d vectorfield with sources (points or very small circles) where all (most of in reality) the vectors move away from. What would be the best method to find these points mathematically?

Comment: the divergence of the vector field

Comment: okay, simple - did not find the answer myself :/ - thanks